# How do we clear grid parameters in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

If I set the jqgrid parameters and then I again want to reset the parameters with new ones, without the old parameters being appended, how do I achieve that?

Lets say,for example:

```
Step 1: jQuery("#list").setGridParam({url:"testJsp.jsp",
                    mtype: "POST", 
                    postData:{xyz: '23fd', 
                              asd: 'were' }
                    });

Step2: jQuery("#list").setGridParam({url:"testJsp.jsp",
                mtype: "POST", 
                postData:{ert: 'trer', 
                          ghj: 'rew' }

                });
```

Now when I do this, by the end of "Step 2" I have a total of 4 parameters, including the parameters from "Step 1". But I don't want this. After "Step 2" I just want to have the parameters of "Step 2".

Is there a way to clear the grid parameters between "Step 1" and "Step 2"?

Answer (score 8):

Set postData to null before setting the new value. You don't have to redefine values for url and mtype if they're not changing.

```
jQuery("#list").setGridParam({postData: null});

jQuery("#list").setGridParam({postData: 
   {ert: 'trer', 
    ghj: 'rew' }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData')` get you **the reference** to object which represent the `postData`. So you can work with it like with an object and add or delete  properties whenever you need or not more need these:

```
var myGrid = jQuery("#list"),
    myPostData = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');

// next two lines are equivalent to
//    myGrid.jqGrid('setGridParam', 'postData', {xyz: '23fd', asd: 'were' });
myPostData.xyz = '23fd'; 
myPostData.asd = 'were';
...
delete myPostData.xyz;
delete myPostData.asd;
...
// next two lines are equivalent to
//    myGrid.jqGrid('setGridParam', 'postData', {ert: 'trer', ghj: 'rew' });
myPostData.ert = 'trer'; 
myPostData.ghj = 'rew';
...
```

Comment: I had the same problem with the setGridParam method updating an existing postData array. I didn't want a complete reset of postData so I used this solution to set new array data. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @Anttu: I'm glad that I could help you. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GridUnload` Method to clear the grid

Comment: I don't want to destroy the grid. I just want to clear the old grid parameters that would be sent to the server and set it with new parameters. Currently, all the parameter are being sent, new and old ones.

Comment: I have had a similar requirement in my application, this was the approach that i felt more feasible, Probably some one might have a more better answer. ... You can Unload and reload the grid again . Just gv it a try

Comment: Hmm.. so by reload, u mean construct the whole grid again? That would take a bit of performance hit, don't u think.

Comment: @Harke the `GridUnload` will unload the grid but leaves the table intact... so u just need to add the row data